# Update node and relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

Are there any best practices on how to update some node properties and set an existing relationship to a different node? I'm new to neo4jclient and neo4j so I'ver currently no clue on how to do this in a propper way.

I do the update of the node like the example in the wiki:

```
graphClient.Cypher
.Match("(user:User)")
.Where((User user) => user.Id == 123)
.Set("user = {tatham}")
.WithParam("tatham", new User { Id = 123, Age = 25, Email = "tatham@oddie.com.au" })
.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cypher doesn't allow redirection of relationships to different nodes, you would need to create a new relationship and delete the old one.

Comment: Okay, that's how i doing it now. Thought there is a more easier way. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there IS something that seems to work like that. If you have the ability to call procedures from neo4jclient, then APOC Procedures has [refactoring procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_refactoring_3) for redirecting relationships, although under the hood it will be creating a new relationship with identical properties and deleting the old one.